# Exception When Casting String Object to SqlString

Tags: c#, types, casting

I have a simple cast issue in following simple c# method

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

...

private void method1() {
    string s = "TestString";
    object o = s;
    SqlString t1 = (SqlString) s;
    SqlString t2 = (SqlString) o;
}

...
```

When casting directly from `s` (in case of t1), I don't get any error but when casting from `o` I get exception:

> Specified cast is not valid.

I have same problem converting from `object` to all types `System.Data.SqlTypes`

How can I cast an `object` that has string in it to `SqlString`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question

```
private void method1() {
    object o = "MyString";
    SqlString t1 = o as String        
}
```

if o is not a string, t1 will be null.

Answer (score 4):

This is because there is an [implicit conversion operator for String to SqlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlstring.op_implicit.aspx).

In other words, you are not dealing with a simple built-in cast: designers of SqlString decided to allow you cast strings to SqlString. They didn't do it for Object, hence the error that you are seeing.

Comment: dasblinkenlight, your didn't answer my question! I don't know how your answer get 3 instant votes!

Comment: I should admit you pointed the problem clearly! may be it is a forgetting programmer, or popular answer of microsoft "by Design"!

Comment: @BSarmady I thought that once you know why "Specified cast is not valid", you'd be able to easily code a solution with an `if` statement or a conditional operator. SynXsiS's solution is very elegant, though: perhaps not as easy to understan than one with a conditional, but I like it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the other answers addresses the question of casting the object reference to the SqlString.  If you are certain that the object reference points to a string, it's simple:

```
var ss = (SqlString)(string)o;
```

If o might hold a value other than a string, you can do this, instead:

```
var ss = (SqlString)(o as string);
```

Or, if you want to go down the (dangerous) path of storing non-string data in string format:

```
var ss = o == null ? (SqlString)null : o.ToString();
```

Comment: Phoog, I think you meant to write `SqlString ss = (string)o;` . I believe your answer is closest that I can get. Unfortunately content of `o` is not always string and sometimes can be null and that's why I used SqlString to carry null to method calling my function. In most cases null is not equal to empty string (or 0 in integer cases).

Comment: I didn't mean to write `SqlString ss = (string)o;` but that statement is essentially equivalent to the one that I did write.  As far as I know, however, the statement should work just fine even if o is null.  If o might be some non-string, non-null value, see the (soon-to-be) edited answer for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this: `var x = new SqlString("hi mom")`

Or, as in the example you provided:

```
string s = "TestString"; 
object o = s; 
SqlString t1 = new SqlString((string)o);
```

A word of general advice: Your life will probably be much easier if you learn to use Intellisense and MSDN documentation prior to posting on StackOverflow. You could've answered this question yourself in about 5 seconds by using documentation.

Comment: DBM, you are quoting my question again here! What I'm trying to say is cast for direct `string` to `SqlString` Exists but there is no cast for `Object` to `SqlString` and then my question was how can I cast `Object` to `SqlString` and NOT `string` to `SqlString`! Please read question carefully before answering it